# set chrome as the default browser on debian wheezy

Tags: google-chrome, debian

install google-chrome

```
sudo dpkg --install google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

each time I run chrome, it ask me to set chrome as the default web browser.
 [image]

---

and I try to fix it in `Settings`
[image]

---

or even uninstalled iceweasel, i still can't set chrome as my default browser.

please help. Thanks in advance.

---

**edit:**

I tried Mr. terdon suggested, but still got the same problem.

here is chrome.desktop

```
~$ cat /usr/share/applications/chrome.desktop

Name=Google Chrome
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognito
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome %U
```

here is mimeapps.list

```
~$ cat .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list

[Default Applications]
text/html=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
```

Comment: Is that setting reflected in your Preferences file? Maybe chrome doesn't have permission to write it to that file? Check ``find ~/.config/ -name 'Preferences' -exec grep "default_browser" "{}" \;``

Comment: @NatefromKalamazoo Thanks for advice. Your command got: `find: missing argument to '-exec'` then I tried `find ~/.config/ -name 'Preference' | grep "default_browser"` but got nothing.

Comment: You didn't happen to include the dash after the semicolon and before my name, did you? Please try this alone first: ``find ~/.config/ -name 'Preferences'`` and if that finds one or more files, search the resulting file with grep like so: ``grep "default_browser" the-filename-you-found``

Comment: @NatefromKalamazoo No, I didn't include the dash. as you suggested `cd ~/.config/` `find -name Preferences` got `./google-chrome/Default/Preferences`. Sorry, my fault I missed `s` in 'Preferences`

Comment: What happens when you search for default_browser using grep? ``grep "default_browser" ./google-chrome/Default/Preferences``

Answer (score 7):

Default applications are defined in the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`. Open the file in your favorite text editor and change

```
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
```

to

```
x-scheme-handler/http=chrome.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=chrome.desktop
```

That should work as long as you have `chrome.desktop` in 
`/usr/share/applications/`.

---

UPDATE:

If you don't have a `chrome.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` just create one with these lines:

```
Name=Google Chrome
Terminal=false
Icon=google-chrome
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;NewIncognito
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome %U
```

Change `/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`to whatever is returned by `which google-chrome`.

Comment: There's no `chrome.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications/`, also not in `/opt/google/` _I use `find -name chrome.desktop` at `/opt/google/` but find nothing_

Comment: @Teifi it won't be in `/opt/google/`, try `locate chrome.desktop`.

Comment: Sorry sir. there must be some problem in my system. `locate chrome.desktop` got nothing.

Comment: @Teifi, see updated answer

Comment: Should I make `chrome.desktop` executable?

Comment: @Teifi no, just `chmod 644`.

Comment: frustrated, it should, but doesn't work for me. upvoted, anyway Tanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The default is /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache, he was read into /usr/share/applications/*.desktop

```
grep -R x-scheme-handler/http /usr/share/applications/*.desktop
```

> /usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop:MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;
>   /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop:MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;text/mml;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;

My approach is to modify the user's ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache will x-scheme-handler/http (http protocol)、x-scheme-handler/https (https protocol) specified by chrome.desktop open.

**save this codes to foo ; and  sh ./foo**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/.local/share/applications/
sed -i '/http=\|https=/d' mimeinfo.cache
cat >>mimeinfo.cache<<EOF
x-scheme-handler/http=chrome.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=chrome.desktop;
EOF
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice...

Comment: I try to use google translator to explain